# How to exit picocom on VS Code terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

Normally on the terminal I would do ctrl+A, ctrl+Q to exit from picocom. But when using terminal in VS code, this doesn't work, seems like it collided with some of the vscode shortcuts. is there a way to exit picocom in vscode without bringing up another terminal and pkilling picocom?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend ctrl+A, ctrl+X to exit from picocom.